# Adding a new instance of an element

Tags: python, xml, instance

I would like to have five instances of the element 'post' with all of it's children.  When I do it this way it just overwrites the first four and leaves me with post number 5.  How do I add new elements in a manner that uniquely identifies them, so that if I ran the script again, post number 1 with a different title would be over-written to post number 1?

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
#root name and name of the xml file
dasub = 'therootname'
#open the xml file
file = open("/class/myname/"+dasub+".xml", 'w')
valid = 0
#I want 5 instances of 'post' using the number = valid to identify them
while(valid <= 5):
    root = xml.Element(dasub)
    post = xml.Element('post')
    root.append(post)
    post.attrib['number'] = str(valid)
    title = xml.Element('title')
    title.text = "a diffent text for each one here"
    post.append(title)
    valid = valid + 1
#write it to file
xml.ElementTree(root).write(file)
#close the file
file.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are overwriting the `root` variable each time through the loop, throwing away the work you did in the last loop iteration.  Move `root = xml.Element(dasub)` up out of the loop and it will work as you expect.